# MDX LastSibling of a Filtered Ancestor (Calculated Member)

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, ssas-2012

Within a Calculated Member in my cube I am leveraging the `Ancestor` function in combination with the `LastSibling` as in the below snipped:

```
Ancestor
( 
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember,
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Desired Member Level]
).LastSibling
```

Is it possible to Filter the set that contains the returned ancestor before pulling the `LastSibling`? For example of the ancestors returned by this, apply the following `Filter` expression:

```
Filter  
(
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Is Actual].Members,
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].Properties( "Is Actual" ) = "N"            
)
```

Ultimately I am attempting from my `CurrentMember` of the hierarchy, to return the last member of the same set that the of the member the `Ancestor` function returned, which satisfies the mentioned filter.

Comment: "Is it possible to Filter the returned ancestors" ....Ancestor only returns a single member - so why would you want to filter it?

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct, the LastSibling still works with that. I am open to the suggestion of another function instead of Ancestor that would provide the set of all members for which the member returned by the mentioned Ancestor function so that I may filter that set and obtain the last member after filtering. I edited the question.

Comment: `Ancestors` maybe the function you require rather than `Ancestor`

Comment: I've been away and since returning I'm considering using instead of combination of FILTER and .Siblings functions, though have stepped away from this problem for the time being though will be revisiting it.

Comment: good stuff - it is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Ancestors` rather than `Ancestor` - a set is then returned:

```
Filter
(
  Ancestors
  (
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember
   ,[Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Is Actual]
  )
 ,
  [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].Properties("Is Actual") = "N"
).Item(0).LastSibling
```

Ok - the above is wrong as `Filter` returns a set but `LastSibling` expects a `member`. After re-reading your requirements maybe this is more what you want:

```
TAIL(
  FILTER                    //<< 3. find the last member
  (
    ANCESTOR                //<< 1. find the ancestor member within [Some higher level]
    (
      [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
     ,[Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Some higher level]
    ).LEVEL.MEMBERS         //<< 2. find all the members of the higher level
   ,
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("Is Actual") = "N"
  )
)
```

But can't you just use Filter, you know the level you want to filter:

```
TAIL(  //<< or .LASTSIBLING  
  FILTER
  (
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Some higher level].MEMBERS,
    [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("Is Actual") = "N"
  )
)
```

Comment: The Ancestors function I have attempted but doesn't work. If I've interpreted correctly the function still only ever returns a set of 1. "A function that returns the set of all ancestors of a specified member at a specified level or at a specified distance from the member. With Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services, the set returned will always consist of a single member - Analysis Services does not support multiple parents for a single member."

Comment: Please note as well the Level expression of the Hierarchy I'm working with is another Level than what you have specified at "[Is Actual]"; [Is Actual] is actually a lowered level than the ancestor level I'm after, perhaps this is part of the issue?

Comment: @whytheq - There is no such thing as `LastMember`.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti nice one Sourav - I'll swap for tail

Comment: also I was missing an `item(0)` - added now. I get the feeling though that the user requires something a lot simpler than we are providing. I just can't get a full understanding of the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Atleast in `SSAS`(not sure of other technologies that support `MDX`) a member can have only one ancestor. So technically `ANCESTOR` and `ANCESTORS` are the same thing.

Now back to your question. If you want to do filtering you can either use a `IIF` statement, or use a `FILTER`.

Filtering using `IIF`:

```
IIF
    (
     Ancestor
            (
                [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember, 
                [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Desired Member Level]
            ).PROPERTIES("Is Actual") = "N", 
    , 
     Ancestor
            (
                [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember, 
                [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Desired Member Level]
            ).LastSibling
    ,
    NULL
    )
```

Filtering using `Filter`

```
FILTER(
        Ancestor
        (
            [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember, 
            [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Desired Member Level]
        )
        ,
        Ancestor
        (
            [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember, 
            [Dimension].[User Hierarchy].[Desired Member Level]
        ).PROPERTIES("Is Actual") = "N"
    ).item(0).LastSibling
```

`.LastSibling` is **really** redundant as there will will only be one sibling ever in this case.

Comment: Hi Sourav - the signature for `Filter` is `Filter(Set_Expression, Logical_Expression )` - so maybe in your second script you need to use the `Ancestors` version

Comment: @whytheq - Tuple/members are auto type-casted to sets. So any function which work on sets work on Members. So, not really needed..